# Changing images using on click with arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

When ever I try to click on the image, the image changes but the next image in the array is not displayed

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            slides
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function nextslide(){
                var images = new Array()
                images[0]= "home.jpg" 
                images[1]= "left.jpg"
                images[2]= "right.jpg"
                var currentpic=0
                var lastpic= images.lenth-1;
             if (currentpic =lastpic)
             {
                currentpic=0;
                document.getElementById('slide').src = images[currentpic];
             }else
              {
                currentpic++;
                document.getElementById('slide').src = images[currentpic];
              }
            }
        </script>   
    </head>
        <body>
            <img src="home.jpg" id="slide" onclick="nextslide()">
        </body>

</html>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Put all the variables outside the function, otherwise you're just creating the same variables every time the function is called.

Comment: Also `if (currentpic =lastpic)` is an assignment, not a comparison. Use `if (currentpic ==lastpic)` to compare the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code. Here is the fixed version:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>slides</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var images = new Array();
            images[0] = "home.jpg";
            images[1] = "left.jpg";
            images[2] = "right.jpg";
            var currentpic = 0;
            var lastpic = images.length-1;
            function nextslide()
            {
                if (currentpic == lastpic)
                {
                    currentpic = 0;
                    document.getElementById('slide').src = images[currentpic];
                }
                else
                {
                    currentpic++;
                    document.getElementById('slide').src = images[currentpic];
                }
            }
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="home.jpg" id="slide" onclick="nextslide()">
    </body>
</html>
```

---

## What's wrong?

1. `var lastpic= images.lenth-1;` You're missing a `g` in `length`.
2. `if (currentpic =lastpic)` To check if `var1` is the same as `var2`, you need to use `==` instead of `=`
3. You're missing a couple of semicolons.
4. You should declare `currentpic`, `images`, and `lastpic` outside of your function to make it actually set the image as the next image.

---

## To try and debug yourself

Always check your browser's developer console for errors.

Comment: You still set `currentpic` to zero every time the `nextslide()` is called, so it will always show the second image.

Comment: Also, variables reinitializing every time, so `currentpic ` will never change. Needs to be outside of `nextslide`

Answer (score 1):

try this

1.)  Specify globallythis variable

```
 var currentpic=0;
```

2.) Change in  images.lenth to images.length

3.) Change if (currentpic =lastpic) to if (currentpic ==lastpic)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            slides
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var currentpic=0;
            function nextslide(){
                var images = new Array()
                images[0]= "http://thewowstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Cartoon.jpg" 
                images[1]= "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/epicrapbattlesofhistory/images/1/10/Penguin-cartoon.png/revision/latest?cb=20141207223335"
                images[2]= "http://cliparts.co/cliparts/kiK/Byz/kiKByzxoT.jpg"

                var lastpic= images.length-1;
             if (currentpic ==lastpic)
             {
                currentpic=0;
                document.getElementById('slide').src = images[currentpic];
             }else
              {
                currentpic++;
                document.getElementById('slide').src = images[currentpic];
              }
            }
        </script>   
    </head>
        <body>
            <img src="home.jpg" id="slide" onclick="nextslide()">
        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should give an explanation as to what you changed.